# Adding GET and POST collection routes to resource route

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, http, rest

**The Situation**

I have a resource FootballPlayer that is accessible at:

```
GET /clubs/id/football_players
```

However, I want a way to access only the football players that are selected, like this:

```
GET /clubs/id/football_players/selected
```

I got this working with the following code in routes.rb:

```
resources :clubs do
  resources :football_players do
    collection do
      get 'selected'
    end
  end
end
```

When I access the URL, it triggers the `selected` action of `FootballPlayers`.

**The Problem**

I also want to be able to *replace* the selection with a set of other football players. A logical request to do that would be:

```
POST /clubs/id/football_players/selected
```

However, if I add `post 'selected'` to routes.rb, it will redirect the request to the same `selected` action.

**The Question**

How can I make the two routes redirect to two different actions? Or isn't this possible, and do I need to distinguish between GET and POST in the action myself? If so, how do I do that?

Comment: can you tell me how do you try to redirect to the post 'selected' action?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Explicitly specify the actions for both methods:

```
resources :clubs do
  resources :football_players do
    collection do
      get  'selected', :action => 'list_selected'
      post 'selected', :action => 'change_selected'
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: But to what action would this redirect?

Comment: @Rits, I've changed it to do what I think you want.

Answer (score 0):

**[EDIT]**

Haven't tried the answer above but I think the difference would be the generated route.. For this case, it would be `clubs_football_players_selected_path` and `clubs_football_players_change_selected_path`. On the other hand, both paths are `clubs_football_players_selected_path` (I'm just guessing).

```
resources :clubs do
  resources :football_players do
    collection do
      get :selected # or... get  :list_selected, path: 'selected'
      post :change_selected, path: 'selected'
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the question, [including an explanation](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the problem, it doesn't explain why or how it answers the question. Please [include an explanation for your code](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762/269535), as that really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion. **Flaggers / reviewers:** [For code-only answers such as this one, downvote, don't delete!](//meta.stackoverflow.com/a/260413/2747593)

Comment: Thanks, I've added an explanation.